# How can I pass nil with other json values as parameters in Alamofire without getting warnings?

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I am getting the warning:

> Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to Any

In this case replyTo variable is an optional `Int?`. And I need it to be an optional value because I want it to be null in the json parameters for the server side if it is empty. I could do `replyTo ?? 0` and give it an initial value, but I do need it to be of null value in json. How can I do this without getting this warning?

```
let parameters: [String: Any?] = ["replyTo": replyTo, "fromId": fromUser.id, "toId": toUser.id, "message": message]

let urlString = "\(Config.URL)/api/message"

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

> The Any type represents values of any type, including optional types.
>   Swift gives you a warning if you use an optional value where a value
>   of type Any is expected. If you really do need to use an optional
>   value as an Any value, you can use the as operator to explicitly cast
>   the optional to Any, as shown below.

```
let optionalNumber: Int? = 3
things.append(optionalNumber)        // Warning
things.append(optionalNumber as Any) // No warning
```

So in your particular case you should be able to do this to suppress your warning.

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["replyTo": replyTo as Any, "fromId": fromUser.id, "toId": toUser.id, "message": message]
```